# How to efficiently use do.call function within a custom function with parallel computing

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, do.call

I have a function that aims to:

1. simulate two datasets under known set of parameters of two models
       (null and alternative)
2. to re-fit both models to simulated data

I want to **speed up computation time** by using the parallel package in conjunction with the pblapply package.

## Here is the function:

```
simulate.data <- function (tree, null_m, alt_m, nsim = 5, do.parallel = T, optTEXT = NULL){

  ## null_m and alt_m are fitted using mvMORPH function
  library(mvMORPH)
  if (!all (class (null_m)[1] == "mvmorph" & class (alt_m)[1] == "mvmorph")) 
    stop ("Fitted models must be of class 'mvmorph'")

  ## define functions
  transform <- function (x){
    if (is.matrix (x)) {
      res <- vector ("list", ncol (x))
      for (i in 1:ncol (x)){
        res[[i]] <- x[,i]
      }
    }
    else {
      res <- x
    }
    res
  }

  find_fun <- function (x){
    class.temp <- class (x)[2]
    if (class.temp == "mvmorph.bm") return ("mvBM")
    if (class.temp == "mvmorph.ou") return ("mvOU")
    if (class.temp == "mvmorph.shift") return ("mvSHIFT")
  }

  ## take arguments of null and alternative fit
  call.fun.A <- find_fun (null_m)
  argsA <- null_m$param [names (null_m$param) %in% names (as.list (args (call.fun.A)))]
  argsA <- lapply (argsA, function (x) if (length(x)>1) x[1]
                   else x)

  call.fun.B <- find_fun(alt_m)
  argsB <- alt_m$param [names (alt_m$param) %in% names (as.list (args (call.fun.B)))]
  argsB <- lapply (argsB, function (x) if (length(x)>1) x[1]
                   else x)

  ## simulate datasets under null and alternative model
  A.df <- transform (simulate(object = null_m, tree = tree, nsim = nsim))
  B.df <- transform (simulate(object = alt_m, tree = tree, nsim = nsim))

  ## refit null (A) and alternative (B) model to simulated data
  # AA: fit null model to data simulated under null model

  library(pbapply)
  op <- pboptions(type = "timer") # default

  if (do.parallel){

    library(parallel)
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
    clusterEvalQ (cl, library(mvMORPH))
    clusterExport (cl, varlist=c("tree", ## tree
                                 "A.df", "B.df", ## simulated data
                                 "call.fun.A", "call.fun.B", ## values of these objects are names of mvMORPH functions to be called with do.call function
                                 "argsA", "argsB"), envir=environment()) ## 'args' objects specify arguments to be passed to do.call function 
    clusterExport (cl, varlist = "do.call")

    cat (paste0 ("\nfitting models to simulated data under the null model (", argsA$model, ")\n"))

    AA <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.A, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsA, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)
    AB <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.B, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsB, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)

    cat (paste0 ("\nfitting models to simulated data under the alternative model (", argsB$model, ")\n"))

    BA <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.A, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsA, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)
    BB <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.B, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsB, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)

    stopCluster(cl)

  }

  else {
    cat (paste0 ("\nfitting models to simulated data under the null model (", argsA$model, ")\n"))

    AA <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.A, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsA, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))))
    AB <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.B, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsB, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))))

    cat (paste0 ("\nfitting models to simulated data under the alternative model (", argsB$model, ")\n"))

    BA <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.A, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsA, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))))
    BB <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
      do.call (call.fun.B, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsB, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))))

  }

  res <- list (A = null_m, B = alt_m, AA = AA, AB = AB, BA = BA, BB = BB)
  class (res) <- append (class(res),"sim.data")

  if (!is.null(optTEXT)){
    attributes (res) <- c (attributes(res), comment = optTEXT)
    res
  }
  else res

}
```

This function works, but it seems that there is **a bottleneck during parallel computing procedures**. I suspect that ***do.call*** function introduced the redundancy but I am not sure...I still need to implement do.call or some other similar function since I need to feed list of arguments within pblapply and arguments are specific to each fit.

To demonstrate the lack of performance during parallel computing, I simulated and used following data:

```
library (phytools)

Generating a tree with 80 tips
set.seed(789)
tree <- pbtree (n = 80)

# Setting the regime states of tip species
regimes <- as.vector(c(rep("R1",40), rep ("R2", 40)))
names(regimes) <- tree$tip.label
tree <- make.simmap (tree, regimes , model="ER", nsim=1)

# Simulate data
library (mvMORPH)

sigma <- c (R1 = 3, R2 = 0.5)
theta <- 0

# Simulate data under the "BMM" model
data <- mvSIM (tree, nsim = 1, model="BMM", param = list (sigma = sigma, theta = theta))

# Fit models
fit1 <- mvBM (tree = tree, data = data, model = "BMM", method = "sparse")
fit2 <- mvOU (tree = tree, data = data, model = "OUM", method = "pseudoinverse", param = list (maxit = 50000))

## run the function
ss.data <- simulate.data(tree = tree, null_m = fit1, alt_m = fit2, nsim = 100, do.parallel = T)
```

On my computer with i3 CPU, I used 3 workers and obtained following results:

```
>fitting models to simulated data under the null model (BMM)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 14s
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 01m 56s

>fitting models to simulated data under the alternative model (OUM)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 01m 51s
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 03m 12s
```

When I run same as above, but without parallel computing (do.parallel = F) computation took less time in general:

```
>fitting models to simulated data under the null model (BMM)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 32s
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 01m 23s

>fitting models to simulated data under the alternative model (OUM)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 09s
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 02m 02s
```

Afterward, I just run part of my function in the global environment (not within the function) but using parallel computing. Code and results are as follow:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
clusterEvalQ (cl, library(mvMORPH))
clusterExport (cl, varlist=c("tree", 
                             "A.df", "B.df",
                             "call.fun.A", "call.fun.B", 
                             "argsA", "argsB"), envir=environment())
clusterExport (cl, varlist = "do.call")

>fitting models to simulated data under the null model (BMM)            
AA <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
do.call (call.fun.A, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsA, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)
AB <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
do.call (call.fun.B, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsB, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 26s    
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 57s

>fitting models to simulated data under the alternative model (OUM)        
BB <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
do.call (call.fun.B, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsB, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)
BA <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
do.call (call.fun.A, args = c (list (tree = tree, data = x), c (argsA, diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE))), cl = cl)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 17s
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 49s

stopCluster(cl)
```

Note that the time of parallel computation in the global environment is considerably lower than within my custom function...

Finally, I just do parallel computing in the global environment but **without the do.call function** which turned out to be the most efficient:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
clusterEvalQ (cl, library(mvMORPH))
clusterExport (cl, varlist=c("tree", 
                             "A.df", "B.df"), envir=environment())

>fitting models to simulated data under the null model (BMM)
AA <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
  mvBM (tree = tree, data = x, model = "BMM", method = "sparse", optimization = "L-BFGS-B", diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE), cl = cl)
AB <- pblapply (X = A.df, FUN = function(x)
  mvOU (tree = tree, data = x, model = "OUM", method = "pseudoinverse", optimization = "L-BFGS-B", diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE), cl = cl)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 19s
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 49s

>fitting models to simulated data under the alternative model (OUM)
BA <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
  mvBM (tree = tree, data = x, model = "BMM", method = "sparse", optimization = "L-BFGS-B", diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE), cl = cl)
BB <- pblapply (X = B.df, FUN = function(x)
  mvOU (tree = tree, data = x, model = "OUM", method = "pseudoinverse", optimization = "L-BFGS-B", diagnostic=FALSE, echo=FALSE), cl = cl)
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 09s
>|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed = 41s

stopCluster(cl)
```

I appreciate any suggestion and/or solution that might help me to implement do.call in my function with more efficient performance in conjunction with parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that **there is nothing wrong with do.call function**, but rather the main problem was a **lack of ram to store objects within my function**.

I tried the function on a computer with 4 GBs of ram and objects generated with the function easily reached it. Thus, a computer tried to allocate data stored in the ram to hdd which in turn resulted in a slower performance of the function.
One solution was to extract individual objects to hdd with `save()` function and remove them from the function environment by `rm ()` function. Likewise, it is always reasonable to upgrade ram memory.

I did both and the function works very well.